# Sign multipart/mixed e-mail with openssl

Tags: email, openssl, multipart

I'm currently trying to sign an e-mail with openssl cms with the following command:

```
openssl cms -sign -in unsigned_message -out signed_message -certfile ca_certs.pem -signer client_cert.pem -from xxx@yyy.com -to yyy@zzz.com -subject sample_subject
```

If the unsigned_message is built up like that (no multipart mail), everything works fine and the signature is correct:

```
Content-Type: text/html

<div>test</div>
```

But if the e-mail contains a multipart message like that:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="sample_boundary"

--sample_boundary
Content-Type: text/html

<div>test</div>

--sample_boundary
Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 

test

--sample_boundary--
```

The signature of the e-mail is wrong. But I don't know why?